# sgelsx does not produce the correct solution

Tags: fortran, lapack, least-squares

I want to find the minimal norm, least square solution of an equation 
`Ax = b`
using LAPACK's driver sgelsx in Fortran. In its [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/db8/group__real_g_esolve_gad3b4ff9ccf12735d7f2e07cbc853c176.html#gad3b4ff9ccf12735d7f2e07cbc853c176), it says that the least square solution is stored as `b` after calling this subroutine but but the dimensions of `b` and `x` are generally different, so how can it be identified as the solution?
I have tried calculating a provided example so I can compare the result of my code with the solution, and it's clearly different.

My program is

```
program test_svd
implicit none

integer:: m,n,nrhs,LDA,LDB,RANK,INFO,i,nwork
integer, allocatable, dimension(:)::JPVT
real, allocatable, dimension(:):: work
real, allocatable, dimension(:,:):: a

real, allocatable, dimension(:,:):: b
real:: RCOND

m = 5
n = 2
nrhs = 1
LDA = 10
LDB = 10
RCOND = 500.0
nwork = maxval( [minval([m,n])+3*n, 2*minval([m,n])+nrhs ])

allocate(b(LDB,nrhs))
allocate(a(LDA,n))
allocate(JPVT(n))
allocate(work(nwork ))

JPVT = (/ (1.0 , i = 1,n) /)


a(1,1) = 1.0
a(2,1) = 1.0
a(3,1) = 1.0
a(4,1) = 1.0
a(5,1) = 1.0

a(1,2) = -2.0
a(2,2) = -1.0
a(3,2) = 0.0
a(4,2) = 2.0
a(5,2) = 3.0

b(1,1) = 4.0
b(2,1) = 2.0
b(3,1) = 1.0
b(4,1) = 1.0
b(5,1) = 1.0

!print *, a, size(a)
!print *, b, size(b)

call sgelsx(m,n,nrhs,a,LDA,b,LDB,JPVT,RCOND,RANK,work,INFO)

print *, b


end
```

What I get as `b` (the solution) is `[1.55172420      0.620689809      -1.36653137     -0.703225672     -0.371572882]`, which is supposed to be `[2, -0.5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved. It turns out that `rcond` is a parameter used to set a threshold below which the singular values of A is set to zero, so `rcond` should be like 0.001 or 0.1 depending on the condition number of A. Unfortunately, I found this explanation in another routine's documentation. I wonder why the author didn't use the same, which is more descriptive, explanation for `rcond` in `sgelsx`.

Comment: Why the `LDA` and `LDB` are larger than `m`? I thought they should be just the number of rows of `a`?